# Нет доступа к файлу hosts

Tags: windows, windows-10, openserver, hosts

Как настроить/получить доступ к файлу hosts? Файл не открывается, не удаляется, у программ нет прав для редактирования.
Из за этого OpenServer не работает.
Проблема появилась после того как hosts был почищен Dr.Web CureIt.
Пытался открыть через блокнот с админ правами, всеравно доступа нет.

**UPD. Всем кто пытался помочь, огромное Спасибо. Проблема решена. Помогла перезагрузка.**

Comment: В свойствах файла на вкладке _Безопасность_, то что прописано? у меня вот `система`, группа `администраторы`, группа `пользователи`. у первых двух полный доступ.

Comment: `DrWeb` то какой нить все еще работает? мб он блочит как-то?

Comment: @teran, DrWeb не работает, А у меня на вкладке "Безопасность" "Что бы просмотреть свйоства этого обьекта нужны права"

Comment: запустите explorer от имени администратора :)

Comment: @teran не помогло

Comment: 1) Проверьте, кто является владельцем файла; 2) Запустите CMD от имени NT Authority\System (`psexec -i -s cmd.exe`) и из командной строки поправьте ACL.

Comment: @Akina а можно подробнее, что и где запускать, как править?

Comment: Сначала попробуйте `ICACLS C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts /reset` плюс `TAKEOWN /F C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: @Akina Access is denied.

Comment: @AFI19 Что? NT Authority\System не имеет доступа к файлу? Вы серьёзно? Ну если даже так - грузитесь с установочного диска, запускайте консоль, удаляйте файл и записывайте на его место новый.

Comment: @Akina  NT Authority\System - это консоль запщеная с правами администратора?

Comment: Нет, это учётная запись такая.

Comment: @Akina как его запустить, так как все действия выполнялись от имени обычной учетки Администратора?

Comment: Этот ваш UPD нужно перенести в ответ

Comment: @AFI19 В первом комментарии я дал команду для запуска консоли, во втором - команды, которые там нужно выполнить. От имени Администратора ничего запускать не требуется.

Answer (score 1):

Запускай *OpenServer* от имени администратора

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Либо поставь галку в настройках "не вносить изменения в HOSTS"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запускай OpenServer от имени администратора, не помогло.
Поставил галку, но как попасть локальный сайт "Пишет не удалось найти адрес DNS"

Comment: каждый раз его потом запускать что ли с админ правами?

Comment: @teran можно у программы поставить в свойствах "запускать с админ правами", просто к сведению...... ну и да, если кому попало можно было открывать и редактировать hosts - было очень плачевно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский можно, но лучше же будет определить чем была вызвана проблема и устранить,а не лечить симптомы. Но как быстрый вариант да.

Comment: @AFI19 `Запуск от администратора, не помогло.` - что пишет? на что ругается? что происходит?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Программа OpenServer запустилась(он всегда запускается от имени администратора), а вот сервер нет. Так же на хост ругается.

Answer (score 0):

Была подобная проблема у меня что не мог правки внести, использовал Notepad++ изначально открыл с правами админа саму программу, далее уже внутри нее через "Открыть" открыл файл host, пробовали ?

Comment: не помогло, нет доступа.

Comment: для простоты открытия hosts, можно создать жесткую ссылку на него с расширением `txt`: `mklink /h hosts.txt hosts`.

Comment: @AFI19 а ты вообще под администратором залогинен ?

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev на ПК один пользователь с правами админа

Comment: @AFI19 смотрите как я понимаю, у Вас Windows 10, попробуйте просто скопировать любой файл в папку Windows на диски C, у Вас запросит права администратора на запись в папку, заодно это даст понимание есть ли у Вас права Администратора или нет. Еще как вариант ПКМ -> Свойства на файле hots и убрать "галлочку" "Только для чтения" если таковая имеется

Comment: @YevgenyIgnatyev файл скопировался\удалился с папки Windows, после того как спросил разрешение. Галку не удалось поставить, нет доступа